# How to access data property from nested hook function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nested

My goal is to access and modify data property **"loading"** from the **mounted()** hook.

The issue is that I have multiple functions nested inside of the mounted hook and I am not sure if I can access that specific context.

As you can see from the photo, this is what I have: **1. mounted()**, **2. Main function**, **3. Nested function**.

A **nested function** is supposed to the one changing data property called **loading from true to false.**

So far I cant seem to find a way to access since this.loading sends undefined since it's out of the reach.

[image]

Comment: Give some code or something you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the `this` reference. Please, try something like it:

```
mounted() {
    var self = this
    function1() {
       function2() {
            self.loading = false
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's now 2019 and ES6 is widely supported by all major web browsers. The var self = this; idiom isn't quite as essential as it once was. preferable to use arrow functions instead. And if the functions are a defined in the vue context under methods you don't have to anything this will still referering to the vue scope

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for a great help